# use jest mockImplementation to mock customized hook in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have one component that that use one customized hook and I need to write some test and make sure I mock the hook. How can I mock the customized hook to have unit test for my component like the code of hook does not even exist?

```
import "./styles.css";
import useAPICall from "@src/hooks/useAPICall ";

export default function App() {
  const { onAPICall } = useAPICall(123);
  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
    onAPICall();
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
///test.tsx all I know is this. but I am not sure how I can use mockImplementation that does not return anything
jest.mock('@src/hooks/useAPICall', () => ({
  onAPICall: () => jest.fn(),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three simple steps:

- Import the module which you want to mock
- Then mock the module
- Provide the return value of the mocked module.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import App from './App';
import useAPICall from "@src/hooks/useAPICall "; // 1st step

jest.mock('@src/hooks/useAPICall'); //2nd step

test('can call useAPICall hook', () => {
  useAPICall.mockReturnValue({ onAPICall: jest.fn() }); // 3rd step
  const { getByRole } = render(<NewApp />);
  userEvent.click(getByRole('button'));
  expect(useAPICall).toBeCalled();
});
```